# Debian.......Set-up, Internet hickups

Tags: debian, sudo, internet

I have a few issues. I'm late in the linux game but i arrived. And already frustrated. I installed Debian 9.9 usb iso image. Installation was done. My issues.

1. My system is 4 years old has an onboard ethernet. But i use a wifi dongle connect to a TP link router in my house because there is no possibility of wiring till my system. So when i had installed, i did so without any internet but have a functional OS. (Debian 9.0 Xfce)
2. Would like to connect the interent. 
   lsusb shows my wifi dongle as Ralink Technology, Corp, RT5370 Wireless Adapter.
   iwconfig doesnt show wlan instead shows name as wlxc83a35c6e9bf 
   gives. how do i inject firmware for it. 
   [image]
3. I have downloaded and written to dvd the dvd2 and dvd3 iso images. I cant even install sudo without internet so i try install from dvd but it kee[s asking for dvd.
   How to know which package is on which DVD.
   [image]
4. Help would be much much appreciated

Comment: this may help https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-set-up-the-ralink-rt5370-wifi-dongle-on-raspian  ... raspbian is based on debian

Comment: you could download Knoppix live CD and boot from it ... then try to activate WiFi ... if it works, then check which modules and config files it is using

Comment: Maybe you could start again with the [non free firmware images](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/).

Comment: You need to install package [firmware-misc-nonfree](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-misc-nonfree),
see https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb

Comment: Use the [Debian CD search engine](https://cdimage-search.debian.org/) to find out which packages are on which DVD.

Answer (score 0):

It is Waiting for you to install the RA Link Linux Driver.

Comment: I hooked up a wired Internet connection installed non free firmware WICD, Network Manager. And Bingo. It works.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your WiFi adapter is the new-style predictable network device name, in this case based on its MAC address.

Regarding your problem with `apt-cdrom`, the man page says:

```
   -d, --cdrom
       Mount point; specify the location to mount the CD-ROM. This mount
       point must be listed in /etc/fstab and properly configured.
```

In other words, your `/etc/fstab` file should contain a line like this (assuming that `/dev/sr0` is the name of your CDROM device):

```
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto 0 0
```

Also, the mount point directory (here `/media/cdrom0`) must exist as an empty directory when the CDROM is unmounted.

`/media/$USER` is not usually the mount point, but a *parent directory* of mount points generated by `udisksd`, the system daemon implementing easy removable media access for non-root users. But `apt-cdrom` does not want `udisksd`-based mounts; it wants a traditional `fstab`-based mount point.